# Passport send callbacks for errors to be able to res.json

Tags: node.js, passport-local, passport.js

How can i catch errorfrom local-signup? i cant find a way to catch them.

The idea is to catch the errors, then send them as a message back to client with

```
res.json
```

Current output:

```
already taken????????????????????
```

node.js

```
router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup'),function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("registration");
    console.log("ERROR?");
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
   //   res.json({type: 'danger',message: info});


});
```

passport:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                console.log("doing local signup");
                Account.findOne({username :  username }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    if (user) {
                        console.log("already taken????????????????????");
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'That username is already taken.'});
                        return done(err);

                    } else {

                        var newUser            = new Account();
                        newUser.username    = username;
                        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }

                });

            });

        }));
```

Update:

I tried custom error callback code, but then i cant get `req` property to send request back to client.

I also tried to move the authenticate middleware to be called within the function `req, res, next,` but then it wont be called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a generic error handler in your app? If you do, you could pass the option `failWithError` to the `LocalStrategy`.

Example:

```
passport.authenticate('local-signup', { failWithError: true })
```

passport code snipped:

```
...
    if (options.failWithError) {
            return next(new AuthenticationError(http.STATUS_CODES[res.statusCode], rstatus));
          }
...
```

And in case, when error occurs, passport will pass the error for the error handler.

Error handler example:

```
...
// it has to be the last operation in the app object
app.use(errorHandler);

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if(typeof error == AuthenticationError) {
     res.status(403);
     res.json('error', { error: err });
  }
  else{ /* anything else */}
}
```

Hope it help you.